# scrolling a text by dragging using the mouse

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to create a text block with a specific width and height. If the text goes over the width and height, I want the ability to drag the text and show the rest of the content. (pressing on the text and moving the text left or right). When I do that now, it selects the text instead of dragging it. I have seen some websites do it using flash, but there is got to be an easier way to do it using CSS or jQuery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go, You can use Jquery UI's draggable() to drag the text

HTML

```
<div id="container">
         <p>
          "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod                                                        tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud       exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."
        </p>
     </div>
```

css

```
          div{

               width:150px;
               height:150px;
               overflow:hidden;
               border:1px solid grey;

             }
```

Jquery--

```
                var o = document.getElementById("container");

                if (o.offsetHeight < o.scrollHeight) {

                   $('p').on('click',function(){
                   $(this).css("cursor","move");
                   $(this).draggable();
                   });

                 }
```

[Check the Fiddle Here](http://jsfiddle.net/GTu79/2/)

Comment: Yes, there are, but hope it helps to some extent.

Answer (score 0):

I would look at one of the mobile javascript frameworks, such as KendoUI, jQuery Mobile, etc.

Another option would be to place a div over top of the text and make that the draggable.